# Spring Boot Endpoints JMX monitoring failure within Intellij Idea

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I encounter a strange issue within IntelliJ IDEA with Spring Boot services Endpoints display.
Everything was alright until today (First time I came to office from a while). Now the my services Endpoints -> Beans, Health, Mappings states :

> Failed to check application ready state: Connection refused to host: 192.168.78.102; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectionException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

> Press Refresh button to reinit ready state checking

This message appear in Beans, Health, Mappings tabs instead of effective information like in this capture
[image: Capture issue location]

The problem here is that 192.168.78.102 is not even my IP address (maybe was, due to DHCP but not now). I can't find where this ip comes from.

Note that if I disconnect myself from local network, the ready state is back to normal (I guess it then rely on localhost IP address).

It seems to be an Intellij related issue, doesn't seems that Spring Boot could be faulty here.
How can I solve this issue ? Is this something relevant to issue declaration as I'm not sure to be able to provide a reproductible case.

Comment: For information Invalidate Caches / Restart... does not solve the issue so far.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot where you exactly get this issue?

Comment: I do post a screenshot. But I can't reproduce the issue at home. Hope it helps to contextualize the issue.

Comment: Today I had the same issue! But I also cannot reproduce it

Comment: Back to office, the issue show up again. For information I use Idea 2020.3.2

Comment: Right click and then select "Remove Configuration Type from Services"

Comment: Done, but the problem still occurs after running the app the simple way.

Comment: What do you mean by the simple way

Comment: I select the app configuration in the upper selector and run it. Maybe I should try to destroy the configuration for good.

Comment: Yes that would be my suggestion as well

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue and the solution for me adding following to the VM Options of the Spring Boot run configuration.

> -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost